# How can I display multiple taxonomy terms on a node?

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, ubercart

I have a Drupal6/Ubercart setup. My products are categorised with taxonomy but we have a requirement that products can be placed into multiple category hierachies. For example, one product might be in:

```
Homeware
   Kitchens
```

and

```
Kitchens
   X Kitchen Range
```

The other requirement is that when displaying the product, the heading should show the breadcrumb of the hierachy as well as the category 
name. This would be dependent on how the user got to view the product. If they went through the menu Homeware > Kitchens, this would be the breadcrumbs/heading displayed and vice versa.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: And what if the user just types the URL?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a product to show up in multiple categories you simply enter all terms from the category vocabulary in the product edit mode. The hierarchy you need to  build up in the menu system not in the vocabulary.

Comment: I just re-read my question, the first half is more just stating how we have it setup, the part im having trouble with is "when displaying the product, the heading should show the breadcrumb of the hierachy as well as the category name. This would be dependent on how the user got to view the product. If they went through the menu Homeware > Kitchens, this would be the breadcrumbs/heading displayed and vice versa."